# Curl impersonate for OkHttp

Tags: curl, okhttp

I need to impersonate Android OkHttp so I am searching for something ready. Curl impersonate is great project but there is no OkHttp support in it.

Can you recommend something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Would this interceptor help as a starting point? https://github.com/mrmike/Ok2Curl